# What is the proper way to fix `error: did not detect an --insecure-registry argument on the Docker daemon` while running `oc cluster up`?

Tags: openshift

According to [this blog](https://blog.hostonnet.com/did-not-detect-insecure-registry-argument-docker-daemon) one has to change the docker daemon:

> ```
> /usr/bin/dockerd --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16 -H fd://
> ```

but I wonder why the error occurs and how to fix it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because the `oc cluster up` command spawns a Docker registry. The `172.30.0.0/16` IP range is probably corresponding to your Docker bridge network. As the registry will run in a container with an unpredictable IP address, you must indicate the IP range (`--insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16`).